# SQL Server how to join on multiple IDs without >> Resulting in changes on a SUM from execution to execution

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [Hours](
    [Activity Month] [datetime],
    [Employee_ID] [nvarchar](10),
    [Activity Date] [datetime],
    [Hours] [float]
) 

CREATE TABLE [Employee_IDs](
    [Month] [datetime],
    [Employee_ID_1] [nvarchar](10),
    [Employee_ID_2] [nvarchar](10),
    [Employee_ID_3] [nvarchar](10),
    [Status] [nvarchar](10)
)
```

Where [Employee_ID] could be equal to one or many of the IDs in table [Employee_IDs]:

```
[Employee_ID_1]=[Employee_ID_2]=[Employee_ID_3]
[Employee_ID_1]<>[Employee_ID_2]<>[Employee_ID_3]
[Employee_ID_1]=[Employee_ID_2]<>[Employee_ID_3]
[Employee_ID_1]<>[Employee_ID_2]=[Employee_ID_3]
```

How to

```
Select [Employee_ID], [Activity Month], [Status], Sum([Hours]) 
WHERE [Activity Month]=[Month]
```

trying to identify all `[Employee_ID]` from `TABLE [Hours]` joining TABLE `[Employee_IDs]` on all 3 possible IDs without duplicates resulting in incorrect `Sum([Hours])`?

There are no duplicates If I use the following as a solution query:

```
SELECT   [Employee_ID], [Activity Month], [Status] , SUM([Hours]) as Sum_Hours
FROM
(
    SELECT [Employee_ID], [Activity Month], [Status], [Hours] 
    FROM [Hours] H1
    INNER JOIN [Employee_IDs] E1 ON H1.[Employee_ID] = E1.Employee_ID_1
    UNION 
    SELECT [Employee_ID], [Activity Month], [Status], [Hours] 
    FROM [Hours] H1
    INNER JOIN [Employee_IDs] E2 ON H1.[Employee_ID] = E2.Employee_ID_2
    UNION 
    SELECT [Employee_ID], [Activity Month], [Status], [Hours] 
    FROM [Hours] H1
    INNER JOIN [Employee_IDs] E3 ON H1.[Employee_ID] = E2.Employee_ID_3
    )T
 WHERE T.[Activity Month]=@Month
 GROUP BY  [Employee_ID], [Activity Month], [Status]
```

However if I try to select

```
SELECT   count(distinct [Employee_ID]) as HC, [Activity Month], [Status], SUM([Hours]) as Sum_Hours
FROM
(
    SELECT [Employee_ID], [Activity Month], [Status], [Hours] 
    FROM [Hours] H1
    INNER JOIN [Employee_IDs] E1 ON H1.[Employee_ID] = E1.Employee_ID_1
    UNION 
    SELECT [Employee_ID], [Activity Month], [Status], [Hours] 
    FROM [Hours] H1
    INNER JOIN [Employee_IDs] E2 ON H1.[Employee_ID] = E2.Employee_ID_2
    UNION 
    SELECT [Employee_ID], [Activity Month], [Status], [Hours] 
    FROM [Hours] H1
    INNER JOIN [Employee_IDs] E3 ON H1.[Employee_ID] = E2.Employee_ID_3
    )T
 WHERE T.[Activity Month]=@Month
 GROUP BY  [Activity Month], [Status]
```

Then I am facing an issue with the Sum_Hours with some minor changes from execution to execution without changes on data tables.

If I insert the result from the solution query into table Solution and run:

```
SELECT count(distinct [Employee_ID]) as HC, [Activity Month], [Status], SUM([Hours]) as Sum_Hours FROM Solution Group By [Activity Month], [Status]
```

There are no changes on the Sum_Hours from execution to execution.

Do you have any idea how to avoid the changing sum directly in the solution query?

Comment: So, do all 3 employee ID fields contain values? If so, which column is the correct one, if not, then COALESCE may be worth looking into.

Comment: Greate job posting DDL for sample tables, however your question lacks DML for sample data as well as desired results. Also, it's always recommended to include the product version tag as well (2008, 2012 etc')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, a simple `IN` will do the job:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Employee_ID], [Activity Month], [Status], Sum(H.[Hours]) 
FROM [Hours] H
INNER JOIN [Employee_IDs] E ON H.[Activity Month] = E.[Month]
                           AND H.[Employee_ID] IN([Employee_ID_1], [Employee_ID_2], [Employee_ID_3])
GROUP BY [Employee_ID], [Activity Month], [Status]
```

Comment: It is working but when Employee_ID_1=Employee_ID_2 or Employee_ID_2=Employee_ID_3 or Employee_ID_1=Employee_ID_3 or Employee_ID_1=Employee_ID_2=Employee_ID_3 we will have duplicated result.

Comment: Excellent! This is solving my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    A.[Employee_ID], A.[Activity Month], B.[Status], Sum(A.[Hours])
from
    Hours A
    inner join Employee_IDs B on (A.Activity Month = @Month
                           and (A.Employee_ID = B.Employee_ID_1
                            or A.Employee_ID = B.Employee_ID_2
                           or A.Employee_ID = B.Employee_ID_3))
group by A.[Employee_ID], A.[Activity Month], B.[Status]
```

Comment: It is working but when Employee_ID_1=Employee_ID_2 or Employee_ID_2=Employee_ID_3 or Employee_ID_1=Employee_ID_3 or Employee_ID_1=Employee_ID_2=Employee_ID_3 we will have duplicated result.